# Button click not rendering Input Field on React

Tags: reactjs

I have a button which should add text box to a form. However the clicking the button is not displaying any kind of text field. I am just putting the code necessary for the functionality.

```
this.state = {
   zoneName: "",
   zonedesc: [{zoneName:""}]
}
<Tab.Pane>
   <button style= {addzone} disabled={this.state.disable}
           type="button"
           onClick={this.handleAddZoneInput}
           className="small">
               Add Zone
           </button>
</Tab.Pane>

handleAddZoneInput = () => {            
  this.setState({
      zonedesc: this.state.zonedesc.concat([{ zoneName: "" }])
  });
  console.log(this.state.zonedesc)
  this.zoneTextBox();
}
zoneTextBox = () =>{
      return this.state.zonedesc.map((zone,idx)=>(
        <div className="zoneInput">
            <PtInputConditionTab style = {{width:'80%'}} disabled={this.state.disable} 
             placeholder={`Zone Description`}
            value={zone.zoneName} onChange={this.handleZoneNameChange(idx)}/>
           
        </div>
   ))
  }
```

The `console.log` statement in the function `handleAddZoneInput` shows that the `state` value of `zonedesc` keeps increasing as I keep on clicking the button but the text box is not displayed which is mentioned in the function `zoneTextBox`.
This works perfectly fine if I just put `{this.zoneTextBox()}` below the `button` tag which will display a single text box on initial page load and keeps adding as I click the button. But I also need to add the first text box on the button click.

Comment: where is your `<form>` ?

Comment: I don't have one.

Comment: oh. you said the textbox would add to a "form" when onClick

Comment: where is this `<Tab.Pane>` in constructor?? and second you have to setState on button Click of the returned value to `render`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the `zonedesc` as an empty array `[]`, and put `{this.zoneTextBox()}` below the button tag, this had to be done because only then the input field will be added to DOM.

Comment: Yes this works and thanks for the direction of the code. I totally missed it that I haven't initialized the array as empty

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the `zoneTextBox` function calling there, you can directly have it in the DOM. The `zoneTextBox` is returning the value but it's returning into the `handleAddZoneInput` function.

Checkout this Codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-2ebgu